# Outputting a single cell from a csv file in python tkinter

Tags: python, csv, tkinter

This is meant to display a single element name from a CSV periodic table (atomic symbol in row 0, name in row 1) in a new label in a tkinter label. The user should be able to entry an atomic symbol, click the find button and the name be output. However so far, it does not print anything, and I am unsure which part is going wrong as I am fairly new to tkinter.

The current code:

```
import tkinter as tk
base_container = tk.Tk()
element = tk.StringVar()

def search(element):
    import csv
    choice = element 
    with open('Periodic_Table.csv') as file:
        csv_file = csv.reader(open('Periodic_Table.csv', "rt"), delimiter=",")
        for row in csv_file:
            if choice == str(row[0]):
                tk.Label(base_container, text=str(row[1])).grid(row=4, column=0)

entry = tk.Label(base_container, text="Enter a chemical symbol:").grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="NE")
text = tk.Entry(base_container, width= 30, textvariable=element).grid(row=0, column=1, padx=2, pady=2, sticky="NE", columnspan=4)

Find = tk.Button(base_container, text="Find", command=lambda: search('element'))
Find.grid(row=30, column=10, sticky="SW", padx=2, pady=2)

Quit = tk.Button(base_container, text="Quit").grid(row=50, column=10, sticky="SW", padx=2, pady=2)
base_container.mainloop()
```

`Periodic_Table.csv` starts as follows:

```
H, Hydrogen
He, Helium
Li, Lithium
Be, Beryllium
B, Boron
C, Carbon
```

Comment: Why are you passing the string `'element'` to your `search` function? Can you show us a few lines of the `'Periodic_Table.csv'` file?

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please elaborate on what happens when you run and what you have tried.

Comment: BTW, it's not a good idea to make a new Label each time you want to update the output. The old Labels will still exist, but they'll be buried under the newer ones. Instead, create a single Label and update its text.

Comment: The string 'element' is passed to guarantee the variable can be used, though I could be wrong about that.

Comment: The first few lines of the csv look like this: H, Hydrogen/
He, Helium/
Li, Lithium/
Be, Beryllium/
B, Boron/
C, Carbon/

Comment: When I run the code, it does nothing basically. I've tried using an enumerate function, but that prints out everything, or once again does nothing if the if statement is included to be selective

Comment: Try with `csv_file = csv.reader(file)`. You are currently opening the file twice. Also for Python 2.x use `open('Periodic_Table.csv', 'rb')` or for Python 3.x use `open('Periodic_Table.csv', newline='')`

Comment: @MartinEvans We can assume that the OP is using Python 3, from the `import tkinter as tk`, so it's correct to open the CSV file in text mode. But it's great that you mention that point, in case Python 2 users read this question, since CSV files ought to be opened in binary mode in Python 2.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few problems with your code. As Martin mentioned, you're opening the CSV file twice. And there's no need to open it & read every time you want to perform a search. It's much more efficient to read it once into some kind of collection, and then perform your search on that collection.

We could save the periodic table data into a list, but it's much better to use a dictionary. That way we can instantly get the element name by using the symbol as the key.

Another problem that I hinted at earlier is that you're passing the string `'element'` to your search function instead of a string containing the element's symbol. And since the periodic table doesn't contain the word 'element' the search would always fail.

We don't actually need to pass anything to `search`: we can get it to retrieve the current contents of the Entry via the `element` StringVar.

Also, as I mentioned above, it's not a good idea to make a new Label each time you want to update the output. The old Labels will still exist, but they'll be buried under the newer ones. Instead, create a single Label and update its text via its `.config` method.

Here's a repaired version of your program.

```
import csv
import tkinter as tk

# Read the periodic_table data and save it to a dictionary, keyed by the symbol
periodic_table = {}
with open('Periodic_Table.csv', newline='') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=",", skipinitialspace=True)
    for sym, name in reader:
        periodic_table[sym] = name

base_container = tk.Tk()
element = tk.StringVar()

def search():
    sym = element.get() 
    name = periodic_table.get(sym, 'Not found')
    element_label.config(text=name) 

tk.Label(base_container, text="Enter a chemical symbol:").grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="NE")
tk.Entry(base_container, width=30, textvariable=element).grid(row=0, column=1, padx=2, pady=2, sticky="NE", columnspan=4)

element_label = tk.Label(base_container, text='')
element_label.grid(row=4, column=0)

tk.Button(base_container, text="Find", command=search).grid(row=30, column=10, sticky="SW", padx=2, pady=2)
tk.Button(base_container, text="Quit", command=base_container.destroy).grid(row=50, column=10, sticky="SW", padx=2, pady=2)

base_container.mainloop()
```